# How can I redirect all non public file requests to my public index script using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I am developing a web application, and I want to provide a basic `.htaccess` file for it. I decided that this structure would be fine:

```
-/
 ├ .git
 ├ private
 | └ lib.php
 ├ public
 | ├ index.php
 | └ css
 |   └ app.css
 ├ .editorconfig
 ├ .gitignore
 ├ .htaccess
 ├ license.txt
 └ readme.txt
```

I have tried lots of configurations, many of them using the `mod_rewrite`, but I have not found any one that does exactly what I am looking for: "**All requests not asking for a file under the public directory must be handled by `public/index.php`**" . That means that a request for `private/lib.php`, for `license.txt` or for `i/do/not/exist.php` will be handled by `public/index.php`, but a request for `public/css/app.css` will return that file directly.

Example. Being the project on the server root:

```
http://localhost -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/hello -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/license.txt -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/private/lib.php -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/public/css -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/public/css/app.css -> shows public/css/app.css contents
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` set to? If you don't want any file outside `public` to be accessible then better set it `/full/path/to/public/`

Comment: @anubhava I would like not to care about the `DocumentRoot` that the server has. I want the application to be as easily deployable as possible, with all the necessary server configuration on the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your site root `.htaccess` as this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# by default show public/index.php
RewriteRule ^$ public/index.php [L]

# if requesting any other dir/file then show public/index.php
RewriteRule !^public/ public/index.php [L,NC]

# for all non-files show public/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
```

Comment: That is not working for me. For php files it gets frozen and for static files it shows them being on public or elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, the php files does not get frozen. I had xdebug on. Still not working as expected.

Comment: The one on the address bar does not change at all.

Comment: Also, I do not want directories to be listable or something. Trying to request for them will redirect to the public/index.php too. So, I suppose the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` is not appropriate.

Comment: I am not getting concrete problem info, What URL are you entering in browser and what is not working as expected?

Comment: Being the project on the server root:

http://localhost -> lists directory
http://localhost/hello -> shows 404
http://localhost/license.txt -> shows license.txt contents
http://localhost/private/lib.php -> runs lib.php
http://localhost/public/css/app.css -> shows public/css/app.css contents

And I want:

http://localhost -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/hello -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/license.txt -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/private/lib.php -> runs public/index.php
http://localhost/public/css/app.css -> public/css/app.css contents

Comment: The .htaccess is correctly placed, and your code is its all content. Sorry

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: You were right. I was testing on a different machine and the server had the htaccess files disabled. I am marking your answer as correct, but please edit it and remove the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` part because I did not want to allow listing public directories. Thank you very much.